# Why list changes fires on whole list

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

I`m using mvp with repository to update items on recyclerview when item at firestore database are changing.

As asked, here is some more code from SharedModelClass:

```
   public LiveData<List<Task>> tasksListening() {
        return repository.tasksListening(false);
    }
```

which lead to:

```
   public LiveData<List<Task>> tasksListening(boolean b) {
            return new FirestoreTasksData(tasksReference, b);
    }
```

Here is FirestoreTasksData extends LiveData<List>:

```
public class FirestoreTasksData extends LiveData<List<Task>> {

    List<Task> tasks;

         for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                Task item = doc.toObject(Task.class);
                tasks.add(item);
         }
 
        setValue(tasks);


    };
}
```

All works perfect except that list is updated in whole even when updating one item.

```
sharedViewModel.tasksListening().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), tasks -> {
            tasksAdapter.submitList(tasks);
        });
```

and here is adapter code:

```
    public class MyTasksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTasksAdapter.TaskHolder> {
    
        private final AsyncListDiffer<Task> mDiffer = new AsyncListDiffer<>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK);
    
        private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Task oldItem, @NonNull Task newItem) {
                return oldItem.getId().equals(newItem.getId());
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Task oldItem, @NonNull Task newItem) {
                return oldItem.geteDate().equals(newItem.geteDate()) && (new HashSet<>(oldItem.getRoles().values()).equals(new HashSet<>(newItem.getRoles().values())));
            }
        };
    }

public void submitList(List<Task> list) {
          mDiffer.submitList(list);
      }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDiffer.getCurrentList().size();
    }
```

Is this a bug or a feature? I was using Firestore UI recycler adapter before, just decided to refactor code.

Comment: That code for FirestoreTasksData looks incomplete, as there are no constructors or methods.  It's also not clear how you are using it, or where the Firestore query is coming from.  Please edit the question to show a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: updated with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to delete post but the rules.

I solved the problem. The problem is that all working good. Feel free to use code if needed.

I just realized that inside observer called another method, which is the reason I see rendering effect as if there were some bug with adapter.

```
sharedViewModel.tasksListening().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), tasks -> {
            tasksAdapter.submitList(tasks);
              checkEmpty(tasks.size());
        });



 private void checkEmpty(int size) {

        if (size == 0) {
            crossFade(noDataLayout, mTasksRecycler);
        } else {
            crossFade(mTasksRecycler, noDataLayout);

        }
    }
```

I fixed that and now all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior. When there's any change to the results of a query/collection, your code gets called with a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) of all changes that match the query/collection.

If you want to see what has changed, you can look at the `getDocumentChanges()` of the snapshot to see those. For more on this (and an example) see the documentation on [viewing change between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

Comment: LiveData has only one method setValue. If item is changed, I should add only those items to the list and pass it. And this is not working. Items that were added previously are removed.

Comment: You can determine what was added by looking at the `getDocumentChanges()` as shown in the documentation I linked. But you can also simply clear the existing list and repopulate one with the code shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implement custom adapter and DiffUtil Callback.

Take a look at [LiveAdapter](https://github.com/RaviKoradiya/LiveAdapter).

You just need to add the latest dependency in Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.RaviKoradiya:LiveAdapter:1.3.2-1608532016'
    // kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION' // this line only for Kotlin projects
}
```

and bind adapter with your RecyclerView

```
LiveAdapter(
            data = liveListOfItems,
            lifecycleOwner = this@MainActivity,
            variable = BR.item )
            .map<Header, ItemHeaderBinding>(R.layout.item_header) {
                areContentsTheSame { old: Header, new: Header ->
                    return@areContentsTheSame old.text == new.text
                }
            }
            .map<Point, ItemPointBinding>(R.layout.item_point) {
                areContentsTheSame { old: Point, new: Point ->
                    return@areContentsTheSame old.id == new.id
                }
            }
            .into(recyclerview)
```

That's it. Not need to write extra code for adapter implementation, observe LiveData and notify the adapter.